# How to export readable HTML links in Org mode?

Tags: org-export, html, org-link

When exporting an Org file to HTML all internal links of the form `[[link]]` are given section indicators of the form `X.Y.Z`.  This makes sentences in which words have been linked unreadable.

### Input

```
* some
A some is also a [[thing]].
* thing
```

### Output

Exporting the above to HTML (`C-c C-e h o`) shows the following sentence in HTML: "A some is also a `<a>`2`</a>`."

### Desired output

"A some is also a `<a>`thing`</a>`."

Comment: I am a little confused by your question. I understand your X.Y.Z example but I'm unclear on what output you want. Would you update your question with some *examples I can copy and paste into emacs for testing*? Something like **Input**, **Output** and **Desired Output**.

Comment: @Melioratus I have added an example along these lines.  I hope the problem is clearer now?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing your links in the Org document as `[[thing][thing]]`. This will create the link with the expected name.